# Custom simple HTML facebook app, not working on IEX8

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I´ve created a very basic html facebook app, with a linked picture. 
Really really basic stuff, but its not showing on IEX8 somehow. 
It does work on Firefox/Safari and Chrome.

THis is the code:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><td><a href="https://www.yourreservation.net/tb3/index.cfm?bf=INSERTHERE&iatanumber=FACEBOOK&arrivaldate=2012-07-30" target="_blank"><img style="DISPLAY: block" border="0" hspace="0" src="http://www.vfmii.com/medlib3/VS_Worldhotels_photo/0/47/674/47674181/47674181.jpg" width="760" height="456" /></a></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Does anyone have a clue?

Thank you